# Why can't I filter a column based on a parameters table's value?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I wanna filter a Date using a table parameters.

First, I created a Parameters table like this :

[image]

Here is the table's values :

[image]

And then I created a Slicer with the table parameters values as a list :

[image]

So what I want is to filter my Date table based on which value is selected on the slicer.

The Date table looks like this :

| v_DATE |
| --- |
| Date |

Date is a "date" type.

Here are some sample values :

| Date |
| --- |
| 13.10.21 |
| 14.10.21 |
| 15.10.21 |

The Date table is used on a bar chart with values that came from an article table.

[image]

So what I want is when I click on the `Last30Days` it filters me all the values from the current date to 30 days ago.

I tried this :

On my Date column, I right clicked and clicked on "New measure".

Then I wrote a DAX code like this :

```
Measure = CALCULATE(IF(SELECTEDVALUE(Parametres[Selection_date]) = "Last30Days", filter(v_Date, v_Date[Date] = "15.10.21")))`
```

I used `15.10.21` as an example value to test my query. But It didn't work, the date isn't filtered.

So what I am doing wrong ? And how can I write my 3 parameters?

**EDIT**

How can I add the values that are not in the last 30 days ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned the measure/column name which you are applying the filter, so I'm assuming it as a Measure(`[Measure_Value]`).

If your user is only selecting only single option at a time, you can use a switch case to filter the expression based on slicer value.

You can calculate the current date using `TODAY()` and on the basis of that you can calculate other time values like this:

```
var _month = MONTH(_today)
var _year = YEAR(_today)
var _last_30_days = _today - 30
```

On the basis of these values and switch case, you can create the measure:

```
Measure =
 
var _today = TODAY()
var _month = MONTH(_today)
var _year = YEAR(_today)
var _last_30_days = _today - 30

return SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(Parametres[Selection_date]),
"MonthToDate",CALCULATE([Measure_Value],FILTER(ALL(v_Date),MONTH('v_Date'[Date])=_month && YEAR('v_Date'[Date])=_year)),
"Last30Days",CALCULATE([Measure_Value],FILTER(ALL(v_Date),'v_Date'[Date]>_last_30_days)),
"YearToDate",CALCULATE([Measure_Value],FILTER(ALL(v_Date),YEAR('v_Date'[Date])=_year)),
BLANK())
```

Comment: Thank you :) Yes sorry I forgot to mention it, but I used your logic and it almost worked ! I still have a small problem if you wanna see, I edited the question

Comment: In place of `BLANK()` at the end of switch, you can use `[Measure_Value]` and remove the selection from filter

Answer (score 0):

In your measure formula you need to add the expression that you want to calculate, so if it's a sum or a count of records that's what you pick.

One way of doing it could be:

```
Measure = Count(Data[Records])

Measure with Param = 
  var selectedParam = SELECTEDVALUE(Parametres[Selection_date])

  var dateFilter = FILTER(Dates, 
     (selectedParam = "Last30Days" && Dates[Date] = DATE(2021,01,19)) ||
     (selectedParam = "MonthToDate" && Dates[Date] > DATE(2021,01,19)) ||
     (selectedParam = "YearToDate" && Dates[Date] > DATE(2021,01,19)) ||
     (ISBLANK(selectedParam)))
  //note: the date filters are just an example, not how you would actually slice these.
  
  return CALCULATE([Measure], dateFilter)
```

But you should look into Calculation Groups, as it is the nicest way to do what you're after. https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2020/07/15/creating-calculation-groups-in-power-bi-desktop/